# DS: How many primitive operations are there in "a<=b"?

Tags: data-structures

How many primitive operations are there in "a<=b" ?
Is it 1 for a <= b or 2 considering a < b or a==b ?

Comment: What does "2 considering a" mean?

Comment: How many primitive operations are there in "a<=b" ? Is it 1 for a <= b or 2 considering a < b or a==b ?

Comment: Similarly, `a < b` could be 2 operations considering `a <= b and a != b`. Clearly there is some sort of issue with this type of argument

Comment: All comparisons of primitive data types usually count as one primitive operation; if it was done with two comparisons you would also count the logical "or" operation. But the only real answer is "what definition of primitive operation are you using?"